# How to add a “Last Modified at” field in footer area?

Tags: 8, theming

I'm fairly new to Drupal and in my research I've seen this question asked many times over the years but I have yet to see one relevant to Drupal 8 (if it's out there, please direct me!). Specifically, I'd like to add a small bit of text in the footer that displays the M/D/Y of when the content of THAT page was most recently modified. How can this be done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can add a View in views, create a block display, give it a contextual filter of node id from current URL, then output the Changed field and select a date format. You can change the label to "Last modified on" and you're done. Then just place that block in the right region.

Sorry I don't have code or pics, posted from mobile.

Edit:

You can add a last modified date in the footer area of `page.html.twig`:

```
{% if node %}
  <p>Last modified at {{ node.changed.value|format_date('custom', 'm/d/Y') }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

This will work also, first is a no-code solution. Example, perhaps your requirement changes and you need to also show the time next to the date. That is just a simple update to the View, no twig edit + git + deploy + etc needed. Some prefer one way over the other.

Also, and I am going out on a limb here - you should know that `node.changed` only contains the last modified time on *that node*. If you changed other things on the page, like menu links in the header, or added new blocks, that date value won't change, because they are not part of the node object being viewed.

Comment: I've placed my answer where you referenced it, because you explained how this all works very well (far better than I could)

Comment: Thank you for both of your responses! I'm thinking the Views method would be the way to go, as the location (which footer column) may change in the future and shifting a block around would easier. I'm a little lost on the options for setting up the View though, as the contextual filters are different depending on what you choose. Would you be willing to elaborate on that by chance?   And as a note, it's really the primary content being modified that is important, so it sounds like `node.changed` will be fine.

Comment: Okay, I got it figured out, though it's not showing on any articles in the news archive. Trying to decipher why myself now, though suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Is the archive a View page?

Comment: It looks that way, yes.

Comment: Views are different than nodes. I'm not sure you could pull a "last modified" date from a view display, and if you could, it wouldn't have any bearing on the content of the page itself.